# Scraping/Cleaning a HTM page into a collection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a file saved as a BLOB type in Oracle database. It's a .htm file that I want to scrape/clean and get several collections out of it.

The problem is that there are no `id` or `class` attributes. What is more there is a lot of rubbish code and in one file there are several different tables. Of each table I want to make a collection.

I thought about manually manipulating with this as a string file but the file is quite big. Could you give me some ideas on how to do so?

Comment: how are you pulling the data from the database? which language do you plan to use to actually do the scraping of the html pages?

Comment: what kind of server are you using? nodejs has serverside jquery / cheerio...

Comment: @MikeCorcoran An app is implemented on Oracle Application Express 5.0 so I am limited to only that technology. User uploads the file and app saves it into APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES table until session ends. After scraping the file I want to further investigate the data and eventually insert it into another database table.

Comment: @Jonasw It's Oracle Application Express 5.0 and the documentation says `Oracle Application Express includes the jQuery 1.11.2 and 2.1.3, jQuery UI 1.10.4, and jQuery Mobile - 1.4.4 JavaScript libraries.`